# Illegal options by deploying firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, tslint

I got an error when deploying firebase functions in GitLab.
I understand that package.json and firebase.json has to have Unix EOL, which I converted with Notepad++, however that didn't solve any problem. What could be the problem?

```
i  deploying storage, firestore, functions, hosting
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint
> lint
> tslint -p tsconfig.json
/bin/sh: 0: Illegal option --
Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 2
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --timeout 15000 -r ts-node/register './test/*/*.ts' --exit",
    "lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch --preserveWatchOutput",
    "serve": "npm run build:watch | firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "serve:all": "npm run build:watch | firebase emulators:start --import ./fs-export --inspect-functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^7.16.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1",
    other deps...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.0",
    "typings": "^2.1.1"
    other deps...
  },
  "private": true
}
```